# AWS EKS "is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole"

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I have followed the documentation for spinning up an EKS cluster that says to make a service role with certain policies.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-ug.pdf

```
To create your Amazon EKS service role
1. Open the IAM console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/.
2. Choose Roles, then Create role.
3. Choose EKS from the list of services, then Allows Amazon EKS to manage your clusters on your behalf for your use case, then Next: Permissions.
4. Choose Next: Review.
5. For Role name, enter a unique name for your role, such as eksServiceRole, then choose Create role.
```

When I create a basic hello world app, it throws an AccessDenied error.

```
Error creating load balancer (will retry): failed to ensure load balancer for service default/nginx:
AccessDenied: User: arn:aws:sts::*************:assumed-role/eks-service-role/************* is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::*************:role/aws-service-role/elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForElasticLoadBalancing
```

The two Policies that were added (AmazonEKSClusterPolicy, AmazonEKSServicePolicy) do not have the iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole action allowed. Are we supposed to add this outside of the policies defined in the guide? Or is this something that should be included in the EKS policies?

Comment: Were you trying to use a load balancer type ingress by chance?

Answer (score 14):

It seems that the EKS userguide assumes you have created load balancers in your AWS account prior to creating the EKS cluster, and thus have an existing **AWSServiceRoleForElasticLoadBalancing** service role in AWS IAM.

As described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/elb-service-linked-roles.html#create-service-linked-role

```
You don't need to manually create the AWSServiceRoleForElasticLoadBalancing role. Elastic Load Balancing creates this role for you when you create a load balancer.
```

EKS is attempting to do this for you, resulting in the access denied exception using the default policies.

Other options to explicitly create the service-linked role prior to EKS cluster creation include:

AWS CLI

```
aws iam create-service-linked-role --aws-service-name "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
```

Terraform

```
resource "aws_iam_service_linked_role" "elasticloadbalancing" {
  aws_service_name = "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
}
```

Or, manually create a load balancer from the UI Console.

Regardless of provisioning options, you should know things will work when you see the following role in AWS IAM

```
arn:aws:iam::<ACCOUNT_ID>:role/aws-service-role/elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForElasticLoadBalancing
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem with kops. Thanks a lot for providing cli and terraform code!

Comment: It's on their list of things to fix: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=286810

Answer (score 5):

I got it worked by adding this policy to the EKS Role:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/*"
            },
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes"
                ],
                "Resource": "*"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I added this as an inline policy and there weren't anymore errors. I wanted to know if this should be included in the EKS policies defined in the user guide.

Comment: I added this policy directly to the EKS role which is generated by the EKS terraform module (https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks)